# How to access a ref bool variable passed into the constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms, ref

I have a main form, which calls a smaller form. In the main form I have a `bool` called `_dataReady` which is set to `false`, however the purpose of the smaller form is to check a few things and see if the data is ready, in which case it sets the `_dataReady` to `true`.

Here is my problem: I call the mini form with an input parameter such as (`ref bool _dataReady`) but the problem is I don't have access to it outside of the  constructor block.

I tried making a `private bool` and set the `ref` to that, but after changing the state of the `private bool` the `ref` did not take the changes, unlike how object oriented programming works.

Here is some of my code:

//this is how i call my mini form within the main

```
new FrmAccounting(MyTextBox1.Text.Trim().Replace(",", "").ToInt32(),ref _dataReady).ShowDialog();
```

This is the constructor of the mini form and the code:

```
public FrmAccounting(decimal Price,ref bool _dataReady)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataReady=_dataReady;
}

private bool dataReady;
```

However setting the `private bool` within the form (`dataReady`) to `true` does not change the `ref` (again unlike how objects work)... that's what I thought would happen.

My question is: how to change the `ref` so I can have the results directly in the main?

Comment: I think the other two answers provide what you need, but to emphasis: Variables like `bool`, `int`, and `decimal` do not get changed at the address level. If you need that to happen, wrap your variable into a class. The class instance, though, does **not** need to be passed by reference since all class instances are already passed by their address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that using `ref` since the field in your class can't be made a `ref`.

I would suggest to wrap your variable into a class. You can pass that class around and use the inner value.

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value {get;set;}
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Wrapper<bool> w = new Wrapper<bool>() { Value = _dataReady };

new FrmAccounting(MyTextBox1.Text.Trim().Replace(",", "").ToInt32(),w).ShowDialog();
```

The value can be retrieved afterwards using `w.Value`.

Comment: thank you.i could use other means but i was just wondering if its possible to make a field in my class a ref.i will use objects to deal with this problem now,as the whole app is object oriented when it comes to data.thank you very much for the help this class solution will also solve my other problems

Comment: You are welcome. There is no solution for this problem using `ref`. Sorry. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1420190/993547).

Answer (score 1):

Your second form is shown as a dialog, so all it needs to do is expose whatever information it wants as a property and the main form can inspect that property as soon as the secondary form is closed, allowing it to do whatever is appropriate at that time.